# Which bank(s) allow you to open AND close CDs online?

Tags: united-states, savings, online-tools, online-banking, certificate-of-deposit

Most banks allow you to transfer money *into* a Certificate of Deposit (CD) using their website.  However, once you open a CD you usually have to call to close or otherwise modify the CD account when it matures.  I hate that.

Are there any banks that allow you to close and transfer money from a CD account using just their website?

(It would be nice if said bank also had decent CD and Savings rates).

**Edit:**
I found this link http://www.bankfox.com/blog/2009/07/29/banks-make-closing-cds-difficult/

It says Ally bank and ING Direct allow you to close CD's online.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: hahah. +1 for "I hate that". Talking to people is so annoying ;)

Comment: Yep, I've opened and closed ING CD's completely online before.  Very easy.  They also have savings and checking products too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure I opened and closed a CD with ING completely online a few years back.

Here's a question in their FAQ that refers to having the proceeds deposited into your "linked account":

http://helpcenter.ingdirect.com/ingd/Topic.aspx?category=C3BNKOCDUS#FBNKOCDU03

Comment: I had an ING account, then moved to HSBC for better rates.  Now ING has better rates.  Transferring it all over to ING now.

Answer (score 1):

HSBC online allows this. Of course their CD offerings today are actually lower than the savings account yield, so I'm not sure why you would want to!

Comment: I have an HSBC account now.  How do I close CD's (when they mature) online?  Do I send a message?  I tried last time when my CD's matured, but didn't see any obvious way to do it.

Comment: You do an account transfer from the CD to your savings or checking account. Be careful though -- it will allow you to transfer from CDs that aren't mature yet!

Answer (score 0):

Nationwide Bank allows this as well.